# How to save State in React Native to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am creating an app that allows a user to select multiple items from a `Flatlist` and the `state` changes once **selected**. However when I move away from that screen, all the **selected** items go back to the **unselected** state. How can use `Firebase` to save that `state` so it doesn't revert when I leave the screen? I am also open to alternative solutions to this issue.

Thank you for your time.

```
export default function StoreCatalogue({ navigation }) {

    const { data, status } = useQuery('products', fetchProducts)

    const [catalogueArray, setCatalogueArray] = useState([])
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState([])
    const [addCompare, setAddCompare] = useState(false)

      const storeToDB = async (item) => {
        if (!addCompare) {
            await db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('myProducts').doc(item.storeName + item.genName).set({
                product_id: item.id,
                product_genName: item.genName
            })
        } else {

            await db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('myProducts').doc(item.storeName + item.genName).delete()
        }
    }


    const clickHandler = async (item) => {

        setAddCompare(
            addCompare ? false : true
        )

        if (isSelected.indexOf(item) > -1) {
            let array = isSelected.filter(indexObj => {
                if (indexObj == item) {
                    return false
                }
                return true
            })
            setIsSelected(array)
        } else {
            setIsSelected([
                ...isSelected, item
            ])
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <FlatList
                extraData={isSelected}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                data={catalogueArray}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => { storeToDB(item); clickHandler(item) }}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name='plus-circle-outline' size={24} color={isSelected.indexOf(item) > -1 ? 'grey' : 'green'} />
                           <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 3 }}>
                              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center', color: isSelected.indexOf(item) > -1 ? 'grey' : 'green' }}>{isSelected.indexOf(item) > -1 ? 'item \nAdded' : 'Add to\n Compare '}</Text>
                           </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
               )}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: How about saving your state in a redux store?

Comment: Hi @Andrew I have never used Redux before... Is there a methord to do it with Context Api `useContext`?

Comment: Okay, then what I would suggest is useContext + hooks to store a Global state: https://medium.com/@pgivens/simplifying-global-state-with-react-hooks-4d7df52d363

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much this article has been helpful. I will post the solution when done. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you leave a screen the state gets reset to original, you can use **Redux** to store the state separately and on an event store the information on firebase once.

Firebase can be costly for this operation since every read and write will be chargeable.